# 'WHERE' and 'find' is not recognized as an internal or external command when starting up selenium server in Windows XP

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, windows-xp

I have a Windows XP (Windows Embedded POSReady 2009), after I've installed the OS and the automation setup that i have. I am unable to start the the selenium server due to missing system files in the OS.

The ff. Files are missing in C:\Windows\system32 folder:
 - WHERE.exe 
 - find.exe

[image]

By the way i'm using the ff. components in the automation:
Protractor Library to start the selenium server: "protractor": "^5.4.1"
OS(Windows Embedded POSReady 2009): https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11196

Comment: not familiar with protractor, but I do know that you need the older version of Selenium if you want to run Java tests using the older webdrivers.  (to run in Chrome49, for instance... not sure about InternetExplorer driver, though... seems like that one may work, but not sure)  The errors you are seeing here, though, are probably other compatibility issues with the packages you are downloading.

Comment: maybe check this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744391/which-nodejs-version-should-i-set-up-on-an-old-windows-xp-machine