# Install NodeJs on Windows XP

Tags: node.js

please how can I install NodeJS on my operating system. I have tried downloading it from their official website but it doesnt run due to the requirement.
Is there another way to get it installed?

Comment: According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37744818/1497533 , node v4 could work, since xp support was dropped in v6. : https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Comment: you could also try to install using [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) or [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) but I would be surprised if this would allow you to install newer node-versions on winxp.